# Find records with more than 1 distinct group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a two column file

```
| object | group |
```

what query could I run to see if the object has more than one distinct group?

for example,

```
object a   1
object a   2
object b   3
```

object b is fine because it has 1 distinct group, but object a has two.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT T.object, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT object, group FROM <yourtablename>) T
GROUP BY T.object
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Which will return all objects with > 1 group.